# How to get form variables in custom form field in symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have this custom form field

```
{# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig #}
{% block gender_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if expanded %}
            <ul {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
            {% for child in form %}
                <li>
                    {{ form_widget(child) }}
                    {{ form_label(child) }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            {# just let the choice widget render the select tag #}
            {{ block('choice_widget') }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

This renders the checkboxes. But i am not able to find how can i get the value of checkbox

i.e `child.form.value` is not working.

Suppose i have entities which is named as tasks in the form.

how can i get the value of the taskid.

something like

`child.form.vars.task.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be in `{{ choice.value }}`

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) to see how the inheritance works.

```
<option value="{{ choice.value }}"{% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ choice.label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</option>
```